# Fix for a Discord selfbot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm really trying to fix this error. How can I fix it?

```
C:\Users\yeet\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:41
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yeet\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js:8:11)
```

#### Source code of the bot

```
const discord = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs");
const clc = require("cli-color");
const ConsoleTitle = require("node-bash-title");

const bot = new discord.Client({disableEveryone: true})

ConsoleTitle("TypicSelfBot version b1.0.0")

bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(clc.red("Your current name is: ${bot.user.username}"))
    setTimeout( () => {
        console.log(clc.green("Ready to use"))
        console.log(clc.green("Prefix is -"))
        console.log(clc.green("Commands: -embed; More coming soon"))
    }, 200)
})
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.content === "-embed")
    {
        let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription("Made by TypicScripter on Roblox, Discord: Typic#0001 or TypicScripter#0001")
        .setFooter("This is a embed message - adding arguments soon")
    }
})

bot.login("") // Put your Discord token here. This wont log your token.
```

I want to make this bot, but nobody knows how to fix it.

Comment: What version of node are you using? Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624456/can-i-use-a-try-catch-in-javascript-without-specifying-the-catch-argument-identi) node introduced optional catch binding in v10.3

Comment: @Phix something like v8.1 or something.

Comment: @TypicScripter Typing `node -v` in a terminal will give you the exact version

Comment: Try updating to at least version 10.3

Comment: Ok, thank you both! gonna try this right now

Comment: didnt work, but i still have some problems with discord.js in installing that it cant find any package.json what's that? please help with that tho

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue regarding one of the bots I'm currently working on. This seems to be an issue with the current discord.js version as replacing the *node_modules* folder with an older intact one seemed to fix the problem.

Try replacing your *node_modules* folder with this one. This resolved the problem for me

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Us8qO-_jUkRRx6oUpEasvsflRAMdko6R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why would we trust random code downloaded from the Internet? Where does this code originate?

Comment: This is the zip archive of a folder directly generated from executing the npm install discord.js command, just an earlier version than what was up to date at the time. If you don't trust it, don't download it. I'm just trying to help.